# Disjoint sets with forest implementation without path compression

Tags: algorithm, runtime

Consider a forest implementation of disjoint sets with only the weighted union heuristics (NO PATH COMPRESSION!) with n distinct elements. Define T(n,m) to be the worst case time complexity of executing a sequence of n-1 unions and m finds in any order, where m is any positive integer greater than n.

I defined T(n,m) to be the sequence of doing n-1 unions and then m finds AFTERWARDS because doing the find operation on the biggest tree possible would take the longest. Accordingly, T(n,m) = m*log(n) + n - 1 because each union takes O(1) so n-1 unions is n-1 steps, and each find takes log(n) steps per as the height of the resultant tree after n-1 unions is bounded by log_2 (n).

My problem now is, does the T(n,m) chosen look fine?

Secondly, is T(n,m) Big Omega (m*log(n)) ? My claim is that it is with c = 1 and n >= 2, given that the smallest possible T(n,m) is m*log(2) + 1, which is obviously greater than m*log(2). Seems rather stupid to ask this but it seemed rather too easy for a solution, so I have my suspicions regarding my correctness.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we only dealing with amortized analysis? Unless I'm mistaken, without path compression the worst case lookup time can be O(n).

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss- If you do union-by-weight you can indeed make this O(lg n).  The idea is that every time you increase the height of a path by one you have to double the number of nodes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to T(n, m) looking fine, though I suppose you could give a formal induction proof that the worst-case is unions followed by finds.

As for proving that T(n, m) is Ω(m log(n)), you need to show that there exist n<sub>0</sub> and m<sub>0</sub> and c such that for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> and all m ≥ m<sub>0</sub>, it holds that T(n, m) ≥ c m log(n). What you've written arguably shows this only for n = 2.